# Sample pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sampling

I have a pandas dataframe, named `ratings_full`, of the form:

```
userID   nr_votes
123      12
124      14
234      22
346      35
763      45
238      1
127      17
```

I want to sample this dataframe, as it contains tens of thousands of users. I want to extract 100 users, but to somehow prioritize the ones with a lower value of `nr_votes`, without sampling only them. So a kind of "stratified sampling" on `nr_votes`. Is it possible?

This is all I managed so far:

```
SAMPLING_FRACTION = 0.0007

uid_samples = ratings_top['userId'] \
                        .drop_duplicates() \
                        .sample(frac=SAMPLING_FRACTION, 
                                replace=False, 
                                random_state=1)
ratings_sample = pd.merge(ratings_full, uid_samples, on='userId', how='inner')
```

This only provides a random sampling across `userID`'s, but not a way to make sure the sampling is somehow stratified.

**EDIT**: I would even be happy if we can split the `nr_votes` into N buckets and we perform stratified sampling on the buckets.

**EDIT 2** I am trying now this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X=ratings_full.drop([nr_votes], axis=1),
             y=ratings_full.nr_votes, 
             test_size=0.33, 
             random_state=42, 
             stratify=y)
```

Then I have to put the dataframes back together. It's not an ideal answer but it may work. I will even try to bucket first and use the bucket column as my "labels".

Comment: You can use `qcut` to divide them into buckets

Comment: @Roim thanks, yep , I have the buckets if necessary, by using qcut, but the stratified sampling is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `np.random.choice` by doing the index slice

```
n = len(ratings_top)
idx = np.random.choice(ratings_top.index.values, p=ratings_top['probability'], size=n*0.0007, replace=True)
```

Then

```
sample_df = df.loc[idx].copy()
```

Comment: what is ratings_top['probability'] ?

Comment: @QubixQ You can define your prob by nr_votes, like (1-df.nr_votes/sum(df.nr_votes))

Comment: Note that `np.random.choice` requires the probabilties to sum up to 1.0, e.g. like this: `prob = (df.nr_votes.max() / df.nr_votes) / df.nr_votes.sum()`. Also, `replace` should probably be set to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

n_splits = 1 
sss = model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits, 
                                                 test_size=0.1,
                                                 random_state=42)
train_idx, test_idx = list(sss.split(X, y))[0]
```